# Why dict is reachable out of function, but list is not?

Tags: python-3.x

Three use cases:

1) Dict `interests` is reachable

```
interests = {}


def get_interests():
    print('interests:', interests)  # interests: {}
    interests['somekey'] = 123
    print('interests:', interests)  # interests: {'somekey': 123}

get_interests()
```

2) List `interests` is not reachable

```
interests = []

def get_interests():
    print('interests:', interests)  # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'interests' referenced before assignment
    interests += [123]
    print('interests:', interests)

get_interests()
```

3) In case of a list, if I simply `print`, it works

```
interests = []

def get_interests():
    print('interests:', interests)  # interests: []
    # interests += [123]
    # print('interests:', interests)

get_interests()
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `.append()` on your list:

```
interests = []

def get_interests():
    print('interests:', interests)  # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'interests' referenced before assignment
    interests.append(123)
    print('interests:', interests)

get_interests()
```

The reason you're seeing this behavior is that by using the `+=` operator you're basically telling python the following: `interests = interests + [123]` -- which declares a new variable called "interests" in the scope of the function instead of modifying the global variable "interests".

By using the `.append()` function you're not creating a new variable but are modifying the global variable instead.

Comment: A saner thing is to just declare interests global inside the function. Then its provenance is clear and you don't get a weird surprise explosion if you ever modify the append line to some assignment.

Comment: @pvg you are absolutely correct and you probably shouldn't do this in production code. But since this question was basically "why do I see this behavior" and not "how can I improve this code", I didn't want to go into that in my answer :-)

Comment: Well, I think you're doing both - you're explaining why the behaviour observed and suggesting a workaround. The workaround is kind of bad, that's all.

Comment: @pvg you are right, but in my case I have a structure like `class\method\submethod (actually function)` and `get_interests()` from the example is this function inside a method (`interests = []` is inside the method before the function). Here I do not want to use `global`, and `nonlocal` here does not work. If there is a better way in such case, ready to listen :)

Comment: @TitanFighter I think that's a somewhat different question and the fundamental issue is perhaps trying to pretend Python has real block-scoping, which it doesn't. Sub-function of a method already sounds funky enough, plus you have lots of other options - function parameters and instance variables come to mind (an instance variable essentially is  'global but just for this class'). Whatever you do, Python's 'explicit is better than implicit' is worth sticking to.